# How to override [] operator in c for my link list

Tags: c, overriding

i wanna override the operator `[](`indexer) for my link list . please help me ;)

```
struct list
{
  List *Next;
}*First,*Last;

First[n]=?
```

Comment: Either tag is wrong or  the description.

Comment: Operator overloading not supported in C

Comment: My suggestion is that OP means C as he uses a struct. Most beginners would shoot for a class; being unaware of the similarities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't override operators in C, so you're out of luck I'm afraid.

Operator *overloading* is for C++

Comment: There is a difference between override and overload. You mean to use overload in both cases I believe.

Comment: Indeed there is. OP uses override. My answer, I hope, contains an implicit correction.

Comment: @Bahsheba ahh I got it. Then I suggest you add more information on what is the difference between the two. An unexperienced programmer would not notice the small difference in the font and may think the two terms are interchangeable.

Comment: ok , how to do it in c++ ?

Comment: @M.Fooladgar or better yet first search for duplicates because there are dozens of question on how to overload operators in `C++` and at least several on how to overload `operator[]`

Answer (score 1):

You can not overload operators in `C`.